# How to combine values with Bash from two files

Tags: bash

I have two files:

Text 1:

```
1 element
2 element
3 element
4 element
```

Text 2:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

I need to get this result:

```
1 element at line1
2 element at line2
3 element at line3
4 element at line4
1 element at line5
2 element at line6
3 element at line7
```

And if I add the  five line at text 1 the result expected like this:

```
1 element at line1
2 element at line2
3 element at line3
4 element at line4
5 element at line5
1 element at line6
2 element at line7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
paste -d '' <(while cat text1; do :; done) <(yes ' at ') text2 | head -n "$(<text2 wc -l)"
```

`while cat text1; do :; done` repeats the content of `text1`. `yes ' at '` generates lines, each being  `at`  (with adjacent spaces). `paste` merges lines of the two plus `text2` with an empty delimiter.

`paste` works until *all* input files are depleted. `while …` and `yes` can stream endlessly, they would make `paste` continue even after `file2` is depleted. Therefore we need to accept exactly as many lines as `text2` has. This is what `head` does.

The approach assumes the two files are static.